# How is Regional Mind Unit scoring calculated at each Checkpoint?

Tags: ingress

Google Support explanation is vague :

> Scores update at the time of each checkpoint. The Mind Units held at that checkpoint are averaged with the running average score for each faction.

It does not explain if the field is done in the first checkpoint or the last one within that cycle.

My understanding is that if I make a field worth 100K in the first checkpoint, the team gets 100K. If nothing happens and I make another 100K in the second checkpoint I get 100 / 2 = 50K. As the team had 100K, we now have a total of 150K.

Is my logic right ? If not, can you please explain how it works with a practical example ?

Comment: I found out the answer from an experienced player. Please correct me if I am wrong but here is my understanding: Lets assume the team scored 900K MU field in the first CP and get900/1=900K. Again lets assume the team makes an additional 700K field in the second CP. The result is (900+700)/2(second CP)=800K. There is an additional 500KMU field in the third CP and the result is(900+700+500)/3=700K. If there is no change in the fourth CP the result is (900+700+500+0)/4=525K...

Comment: If you make an ADDITIONAL 700K in the second CP (without losing the field from the first CP) the calculation would be like this : First CP score 900K + the ADDITIONAL second CP score 700K + the field score from the first CP calculated again for the second CP 900K, which would be formulated like this : (900K + 700K + 900K) / 2 = 1250K

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At each checkpoint, all currently-standing fields in the region are measured. The region's team score is then averaged with any previous checkpoints in the cycle.

> **CP 1:**
>
> - Set up fields for 900,000
> - Running score is 900,000 / 1 = 900,000
>
> **CP 2:**
>
> - Opposition takes down 300,000 worth of fields
> - Measurement at checkpoint is 600,000
> - Running score is (900,000 + 600,000) / 2 = 750,000
>
> **CP 3:**
>
> - Put 150,000 worth of fields back up.
> - Measurement at checkpoint is 750,000
> - Running score is (900,000 + 600,000 + 750,000) / 3 = 750,000

It's possible to use one very big field at one checkpoint to inflate that average for a while. (This is moderately common in my region, where one side is significantly outnumbered -- they can't keep lots of smaller fields up for an extended period of time because of lack of manpower, so they make up for it with planning and coordination to have short-lived but very large fields at least once per cycle.)

> **CP 1:**
>
> - Set up fields for 5,000
> - Running score is 5,000 / 1 = 5,000
>
> **CP 2:**
>
> - Set up GIANT FIELD for 2,000,000
> - Measurement at checkpoint is 2,005,000
> - Running score is (5,000 + 2,005,000) / 2 = 1,005,000
>
> **CP 3:**
>
> - Opposition destroys your giant field.
> - Measurement at checkpoint is 5,000
> - Running score is (5,000 + 2,005,000 + 5,000) / 3 = 671,667
>
> **CP 4:**
>
> - Measurement at checkpoint is 5,000
> - Running score is (5,000 + 2,005,000 + 5,000 + 5,000) / 4 = 505,000

Fields need to be standing at checkpoint to count. If I make that two million MU field and it is taken down before checkpoint, it isn't measured or recorded in the scores -- just in my agent profile.

Answer (score 2):

The team score at each checkpoint is the average of the MU controlled by each team at the preceding checkpoints.  This means if 1 team is way ahead half way through, they could stop playing, lose their fields eventually, and still win the cycle.  The next cycle would start, however, and the score would be the average of MU active at each checkpoint.

Personal score is how many MU you have gained since the beginning of the Cycle.  It doesn't count what was up at the end of the last cycle... so to stay at the top, your fields have to either be destroyed and you rebuild them, or you build more.  It also does not matter whether your MU gained was active at the checkpoint, and even counted on the team score.  I have seen mega fields destroyed before the checkpoint, but the players responsible for the fields were listed as the top agents in the region, though they were thousands of miles away.

Agent "Now" is simply how much MU you currently control (and is a part of your team score).

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment yet Erica answer, that is correct for the Team score.

For the ranking of agent players in the region, it's different so it can be confusing if you don't know it. If you make a two million MU field and it is taken down before checkpoint, you are likely to be amongs the first in agent rankings for the cycle (even if this has not contributed for the team.)

If you make a big field and it stay alive all the cycle, it will not count more than if it's take down soon. If it still alive for next cycle, it counts for the team but you will not be in the area ranked agents for it.

And the score done in Agent stast "now" is still sometihng different.